# How to make firestore search results display in flutter?

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, google-cloud-firestore, search

I am trying to display the IMEI numbers related to the search of the user, but I don't know where I'm doing wrong the results  are not appearing. I'm new to flutter. This is my code. please help

```
class _HomeState extends State<Home> {
  TextEditingController seachtf = TextEditingController();
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final Stream<QuerySnapshot> _usersStream = FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection('imei')
        .where(
          'number',
          isEqualTo: seachtf.text,
        )
        .snapshots();
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Container(
          padding: EdgeInsets.only(
            left: 20,
            right: 10,
          ),
          child: TextField(
            controller: seachtf,
            decoration: InputDecoration(
              hintText: 'Search',
            ),
            onChanged: (value) {
              setState(() {});
            },
          ),
        ),
      ),
      body: StreamBuilder(
        stream: _usersStream,
        builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.hasError) {
            return Text("something is wrong");
          }
          if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
            return Center(
              child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
            );
          }

          return Container(
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12),
            ),
            child: ListView.builder(
              itemCount: snapshot.data!.docs.length,
        
              itemBuilder: (_, index) {
                      var data = snapshot.data!.docs[index].data()
                          as Map<String, dynamic>;
                return Card(
                  child: ListTile(
                    title: Text(
                     data['number'].toString(),
                    ),
                  ),
                );
              },
            ),
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Please don't work around a rule of this community by copy/pasting the same single line explanation multiple times. Instead think of what additional information we might need to help you. For example: if you step through this code line-by-line in a debugger and check all variables on each line, which is the **first** line that doesn't do what you expect it to do?

Answer (score 0):

First of all the way you are implementing the "search method" is way complicated and inefficient.

Flutter has pre-built implementation called '[SearchDelegate](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/SearchDelegate-class.html)'. If you check it's documentation and search for it's use examples with Firebase Firestore database it will make your life much easier.